# Inspecting the contents of a Google Guice module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is it possible to get a list of every class available from a Guice module.
What hasn't worked so far ...
 - Loading it into an injector and inspecting the bindings generated
 - Using `Elements` and inspecting
 - Injecting a Grapher

Is there anything possible like eagerly generating bindings but not the final objects themselves?

Comment: I don't think it is possible Maybe extend the AbstractModule and override the methods to hold the data you need?

Comment: Check out the inspecting modules docs: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InspectingModules